# How to get parent pid from script?

Tags: shell

./tesh.sh 192.168.1.10 elastic01

```sh
# this is script
ip=$1
node=$2

pid=`ps -ef | grep $node | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print \$2}'`

echo $pid
```

run this script output:
**2234** (I want to get)
2313
3241

Comment: Do you have bash? if so, then `echo $PPID`

Comment: If you want just the top entry, use awk 'NR==1 { print $2 }'

Comment: @RamanSailopal Achieved the goal, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the top entry, use

```
awk 'NR==1 { print $2 }'
```

Process only the first line with NR==1 and print only the second space delimited field.